# When using a path string in a shell script, it would be trans to a string containing children

Tags: bash, shell

Here is some bash code

```sh
path='*'
echo $path
```

If I execute the code in terminal directly, the output is

```sh
*
```

But if I put it in a shell script e.g., **test.sh**. Then I execute the **test.sh**, the output will be like this

```sh
test.sh file1 file2 file3
```

I got a string contains all items under the path.

Why the two outputs is different? If I want the second output to be the first one, which means do not trans a path string when I use it, what should I do?

Comment: Since `bash` does pathname expansion after parameter expansion, you will get the same result in your terminal, provided you *do* run bash there. I just tried it with my bash 4.4. What does  `echo $BASH_VERSION` say in your terminal?

Comment: So, if you do a `echo $path` , and `path` is set to `*`, you get a list of all non-hidden files in the working directory passed to `echo`. Only if there are no files, an `*` will be printed to stdout. But this too is same behaviour whether bash (or Posix shell) is run interactively or from a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested a little. You could change your script to this:

```
path='*'
echo "$path"
```

and it will print * instead of files if you run it as a bash script.

Seems echo can be used as a alternative of `ls` command:

`echo *` means list all files under current folder.

`echo *.jpg` will list all files with jpg as suffix, and if there is no such file in current folder, `echo *.jpg` will just print "*.jpg".

I think this answer should be posted as a comment, since I don't really know why `echo` command behave like this. But I do not have enough reputation to add comment, so...

Comment: This is not a behaviour of the `echo` command, but a property of `bash`. There is a bash flag where you can control this behaviour.

Comment: Please explain further. A link would be helpful. I'd like to know more about it, but I do not even know how to search it on google.

Comment: For instance, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) or [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

Comment: thanks. I always go direct to the official doc when learning a new language. It strikes me when I opened the links you shared, that after years of intensive bash using, I've never checked the official doc. thanks so much for opening the hidden door for me.